# ChartJS plugin with live label update

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am currently using the chartJS plugin to draw a chart on my website which, of course, works wonderful.

However, I have it labelled on months now but I want the user to be able to switch to a day view as well so I made a button with an onclick event, I thought that would work but unfortunately it doesn't.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="days();">Sort On Days</button>
```

JQUERY:

```
var label = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"]; // Months here

       function days()
       {
           var label = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07"]; // Days
       } 

var lineChartData = {
                labels: label,
```

How can I make it so that it will live update? Nothing happens currently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an update() after updating the labels. And you have to update the labels on the chart object.

```
window.days = function()
{
    myLineChart.scale.xLabels = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07"]; // Days
    myLineChart.update();
}
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rxoLjd92/

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly for me. Is it possible to edit the data this way as well? I tried myLineChart.scale.data but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: It is possible - for instance, myLineChart.datasets[0].points[2].value = 10 will set first dataset's 3rd data point. You'll also need to use the addData() and removeData() methods http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-prototype-methods) if the number of points change. It would be far easier to destroy() the chart (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods) and recreate it OR use something like https://github.com/carlcraig/tc-angular-chartjs.